# DynamoDB Table Count using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I need to get count of records in my DynamoDB table using Node.js?

Simply, How to write Node.js snippet for same?

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name dev-xxx-table --select "COUNT"
```

Tried https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property

```
const params = {
    TableName: Table(),
    Select: COUNT
  }

  try {
    const count = await dynamoDb.query(params).promise()
```

but got

> "ReferenceError: COUNT is not defined",

I couldn't find anything in the documentation for the same(or finding aggregation for DynamoDB table). Any lead will be appreciated.

Comment: Nodejs sdk has `scan`. So what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me like there's two errors in the code, first you're using the wrong function (`query` instead of `scan`) and second, you're not passing `COUNT` as a String, but as a variable, which is why you're getting the error. Try the following code (untested):

```js
const params = {
  TableName: Table(),
  Select: "COUNT",
};
const count = await dynamoDb.scan(params).promise();
```

That being said, be aware that this is a very expensive and probably slow operation that you do not want to be doing on a very large dataset.